# DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn Checked

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tengo un check en el DataGridView, queria saber si es posible que cada vez que se agregue un valor automáticamente aparezca como checked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puede hacerse, claro. Primero, podrías controlar cada vez que se añade un nuevo row al `DataGridView` manejando el evento `RowsAdded` y ahí establecer el valor de la celda del tipo `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` de esta forma:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    // e.RowIndex proporciona el índice de la fila que se acaba de añadir
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["NombreDeTuCeldaCheckBox"].Value = true;
}
```

Pero ojo, si tu `DataGridView` tuviera datos previos, antes guardaría la cantidad de registros existentes en una variable y comprobaría que el nuevo índice fuera superior a esa cantidad, o de otra forma marcarías todos los CheckBox.